# Firebase A/B Test User Distribution not correct, set 100% users but most users are remote config server side default value

Tags: firebase, firebase-ab-testing

We are doing firebase remote config + AB test.  A/B test control group and variant: we set 100% users with value3 and Value4

When we check the data, for 100 users we see the distribution:

1. value1 (in app default value):                    1 user
2. value2 (remote config server side default value): 70 users
3. value3 (ab test control group):                   14 users
4. value4 (ab test variant A):                       15 users

We are not sure what's wrong. It suppose to be value3 50 users and value4 50 users.
We set the cache to be 24 hours and once get firebase server side value, we will override in app default value(value1)

Comment: Hey Heidi, can you please file a support ticket?  We will need a bit more info to dig into what is going on here.  https://firebase.google.com/support/

Comment: Hi Fenmarel, thank you for pay attention to this problem. I already submit a support ticket.